# how to stop linux framebuffer to clear automatically while drawing multiple frames

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I am writing a gif decoder, This image is an animated image.When I write the first frame, it displays fine. When, I display the second frame, it displays only the changed pixels. Other pixels are automatically changed to black. I don't know why?.

My first frame has the complete picture.
The second frame has again only the pixel changed and it contains the rest of the unchanged pixels.

Now, when I draw the second buffer, it  redraws the unchanged pixels also. And the unchanged pixels are drawn as black ( or precisely in monitor I see these unchanged pixels are absent). That's when it has to draw the second frame.It draws the changed pixels( which is correct), but it re-draws the unchanged pixel as well. And this unchanged pixel are seen as a black ( that is no color). I feel it is a refreshing issue. Or It could be something else. Help is appreciated.

Required: It should redraw the complete image.
In short, this is the snippet of my function.

Unfortunately, it clears off the previous display - linux framebuffer.
I want to stop clearning the linux framebuffer.

here is the complete file.

```
/** This is using the Direct Fb calls here; and is tightly coupled with Linux Framebuffer **/
static int fbfd = 0;
static struct fb_var_screeninfo vinfo;
static struct fb_fix_screeninfo finfo;
static long int screensize = 0;
static char *fbp = 0;
static int x = 0, y = 0;
static long int location = 0;

/** This is a clone to linux Frame buffer, and will be called to dump on Framebuffer **/
char *local_display_mem;

/** local functions **/
static void SetBackground(FrameData *tempInfo);
static void SetPixel(char *fbp, unsigned int x, unsigned int y, Byte red, Byte green, Byte blue);


/** This is the entry function to initialize the display **/
void display_init()
{

    // Open the file for reading and writing
    fbfd = open("/dev/fb0", O_RDWR);
    if (fbfd == -1)
    {
        perror("cannot open framebuffer device");
        exit(1);
    }
    #ifdef DEBUG
    printf("The framebuffer device was opened successfully.\n");
    #endif

    /** Read the Screen Information **/
        if (ioctl(fbfd, FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO, &finfo) == -1)
        {
          perror("Driver error-- reading fixed information");
          exit(1);
        }

    // Get variable screen information

    if (ioctl(fbfd, FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO, &vinfo) == -1)
    {
        perror("Error reading variable information");
        exit(1);
    }

    #ifdef DEBUG
    printf("%dx%d, %dbpp\n", vinfo.xres, vinfo.yres, vinfo.bits_per_pixel);
    #endif

      // Figure out the size of the screen in bytes
    screensize = vinfo.xres * vinfo.yres * vinfo.bits_per_pixel / 8;

    // Map the device to memory
    fbp = (char *)mmap(0, screensize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fbfd, 0);

    local_display_mem = (char*)malloc(screensize);

    if ((int)fbp == -1)
     {
        perror("Error: mmap failed\r\n");
        exit(1);
     }
    #ifdef DEBUG
    printf("The framebuffer device was mapped to memory successfully.\n");
    #endif

    printf("Shreyas..Display Initialized..\r\n");


   //munmap(fbp, screensize);
   //close(fbfd);

}

/** This function is called by gif_read to display the Image **/

void Display(FrameData *FrameInfo)
{

    short int ImageStartX = 0;
    short int ImageStartY = 0;
    int Index = 0;

    printf("\r\n INFO: Display Called.\r\n");

    while(1)
    {

        Index = 0;
        ImageStartX = (FrameInfo->frameScreenInfo.LeftPosition);
        ImageStartY = (FrameInfo->frameScreenInfo.TopPosition);


        while(ImageStartY < ((FrameInfo->frameScreenInfo.ImageHeight)+(FrameInfo->frameScreenInfo.TopPosition)))
        {

            while(ImageStartX < ((FrameInfo->frameScreenInfo.ImageWidth)+(FrameInfo->frameScreenInfo.LeftPosition)))
            {
                if(FrameInfo->frame[Index] != FrameInfo->transperencyindex)
                {
                  SetPixel(local_display_mem,ImageStartX,ImageStartY,((FrameInfo->CMAP)+(FrameInfo->frame[Index]))->Red,((FrameInfo->CMAP)+(FrameInfo->frame[Index]))->Green,((FrameInfo->CMAP)+(FrameInfo->frame[Index]))->Blue);

                }


                Index++;
                ImageStartX++;
            }


            ImageStartY++;


            ImageStartX=(FrameInfo->frameScreenInfo.LeftPosition);
        }

        printf("INFO:..Dumping Framebuffer\r\n");

        memcpy(fbp,local_display_mem,screensize);

        /** Tune this multiplication to meet the right output on the display **/
        usleep((FrameInfo->InterFrameDelay)*100000);

        if( FrameInfo->DisposalMethod == 2)
        {
            printf("set the Background\r\n");
            SetBackground(FrameInfo);
        }
        FrameInfo = FrameInfo->Next;

     }


}

static void SetBackground(FrameData *tempInfo)
{

    unsigned int ImageStartX=0;
    unsigned int ImageStartY=0;


    ImageStartX=(tempInfo->frameScreenInfo.LeftPosition);
    ImageStartY=(tempInfo->frameScreenInfo.TopPosition);


    while(ImageStartY<(tempInfo->frameScreenInfo.ImageHeight))
    {

        while(ImageStartX<(tempInfo->frameScreenInfo.ImageWidth))
        {

           SetPixel(local_display_mem,ImageStartX,ImageStartY,255,255,255);

            ImageStartX++;
        }

        ImageStartX=(tempInfo->frameScreenInfo.LeftPosition);
        ImageStartY++;


    }



}

static void SetPixel(char *fbp_lc, unsigned int x, unsigned int y, Byte red, Byte green, Byte blue)
{
           //printf("Shreyas..set pixel called\r\n");
           location = (x+vinfo.xoffset) * (vinfo.bits_per_pixel/8) +
                       (y+vinfo.yoffset) * finfo.line_length;

            if (vinfo.bits_per_pixel == 32)
            {
                *(fbp_lc + location) =     blue;        // Some blue
                *(fbp_lc + location + 1) = green;     // A little green
                *(fbp_lc + location + 2) = red;    // A lot of red
                *(fbp_lc + location + 3) = 0;      // No transparency
                //location += 4;
            }
            else
            { //assume 16bpp
                unsigned short int t = red<<11 | green << 5 | blue;
                *((unsigned short int*)(fbp_lc + location)) = t;
            }

             //printf("Shreyas..set pixel exit called\r\n");

}







/** This is windows version of display function, and it works correctly.
void Display(FrameData *FrameInfo)
{


    short int ImageStartX=0;
    short int ImageStartY=0;
    int Index=0;



    DisplayCntrl=GetDC(hWnd);

        printf("Shreyas.. Display Init is called\r\n");

    //display_init();


    while(1)
    {

        Index=0;
        ImageStartX=(FrameInfo->frameScreenInfo.LeftPosition);
        ImageStartY=(FrameInfo->frameScreenInfo.TopPosition);   

        while(ImageStartY<((FrameInfo->frameScreenInfo.ImageHeight)+(FrameInfo->frameScreenInfo.TopPosition)))
        {

            while(ImageStartX<((FrameInfo->frameScreenInfo.ImageWidth)+(FrameInfo->frameScreenInfo.LeftPosition)))
            {
                if(FrameInfo->frame[Index]!=FrameInfo->transperencyindex)
                    SetPixel(DisplayCntrl,ImageStartX,ImageStartY,RGB(((FrameInfo->CMAP)+(FrameInfo->frame[Index]))->Red,((FrameInfo->CMAP)+(FrameInfo->frame[Index]))->Green,((FrameInfo->CMAP)+(FrameInfo->frame[Index]))->Blue));

                Index++;
                ImageStartX++;
            }


            ImageStartY++;


            ImageStartX=(FrameInfo->frameScreenInfo.LeftPosition);
        }



        Sleep((FrameInfo->InterFrameDelay*10));
        WaitForSingleObject(hWnd,10); 
         if(    FrameInfo->DisposalMethod==2)
        {

            SETBACKGROUND(FrameInfo);
        }
        FrameInfo=FrameInfo->Next;

    }



}
```

This is the windows version of the same code.

```
extern  hWnd;
HDC DisplayCntrl;



void SETBACKGROUND(FrameData *tempInfo)
{

    unsigned int ImageStartX=0;
    unsigned int ImageStartY=0;



    ImageStartX=(tempInfo->frameScreenInfo.LeftPosition);
    ImageStartY=(tempInfo->frameScreenInfo.TopPosition);


    while(ImageStartY<(tempInfo->frameScreenInfo.ImageHeight))
    {

        while(ImageStartX<(tempInfo->frameScreenInfo.ImageWidth))
        {



            SetPixel(DisplayCntrl,ImageStartX,ImageStartY,RGB(255,255,255));

            ImageStartX++;
        }

        ImageStartX=(tempInfo->frameScreenInfo.LeftPosition);
        ImageStartY++;


    }



}


void Display(FrameData *FrameInfo)
{



    short int ImageStartX=0;
    short int ImageStartY=0;
    int Index=0;



    DisplayCntrl=GetDC(hWnd);


     printf("the size of short int is %d",sizeof(short int));

    while(1)
    {

        Index=0;
        ImageStartX=(FrameInfo->frameScreenInfo.LeftPosition);
        ImageStartY=(FrameInfo->frameScreenInfo.TopPosition);   

        while(ImageStartY<((FrameInfo->frameScreenInfo.ImageHeight)+(FrameInfo->frameScreenInfo.TopPosition)))
        {

            while(ImageStartX<((FrameInfo->frameScreenInfo.ImageWidth)+(FrameInfo->frameScreenInfo.LeftPosition)))
            {
                if(FrameInfo->frame[Index]!=FrameInfo->transperencyindex)
                {
                    SetPixel(DisplayCntrl,ImageStartX,ImageStartY,RGB(((FrameInfo->CMAP)+(FrameInfo->frame[Index]))->Red,((FrameInfo->CMAP)+(FrameInfo->frame[Index]))->Green,((FrameInfo->CMAP)+(FrameInfo->frame[Index]))->Blue));
                }

                Index++;
                ImageStartX++;
            }


            ImageStartY++;


            ImageStartX=(FrameInfo->frameScreenInfo.LeftPosition);
        }



        Sleep((FrameInfo->InterFrameDelay*10));
        WaitForSingleObject(hWnd,10); 
    if( FrameInfo->DisposalMethod==2)
        {

            SETBACKGROUND(FrameInfo);
        }
        FrameInfo=FrameInfo->Next;

    }



}
```

Comment: I don't see your local_display_mem declaration and initial clear/etc., but it looks like this is your temporary buffer that caches previous frame. And then you copy this data to framebuffer, right? So what's the matter if it does clear something (which i think it doesn't, btw), if you still have a copy and you putting it on the next frame?

Comment: Does sleep can make the difference here?

Comment: No it doesn't, and i don't see why it relevant. Based on comments on answer, i don't think anyone could help you if you can't validate contents of local_display_mem and say it's wrong or right (debugger, dump to file, whatever). But if what you said is indeed true, than you have a problem with understanding what memcpy is - it replaces target memory contents with source ones. It does not know anything about transparency, colors, or discarded pixels. It all must be done in source buffer before copying. I really hope it's not your case and sorry if i'm wrong.

Comment: I have shared the entire code now. Hope this can lead to an answer. The boggling part is that it works on Windows - the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use a local memory buffer `local_display_mem`, it doesn't matter if somebody would clear the framebuffer - the `memcpy` will overwrite every pixel.

This means that the condition `FrameInfo->frame[Index] != FrameInfo->transperencyindex` is always `true` for some reason since that would cause the algorithm to set each pixel again instead of only updating the changed pixels.

Comment: But probably a different GIF loading library? To test my hypothesis, count the number of calls to `SetPixel` per frame. If I'm right, then this number will be `ImageHeight*ImageWidth` for all frames on Linux.

Comment: Let me give some more detail on it.

Comment: Let me give some more detail on it. First a complete image is formed and is dumped on to the frame buffer. Now, the next frame has only the changes, It check before writing whether it is not a transparent index or not. If the transparent index is there, it skips that particular setpixel.

Comment: By the way, I am not setting the a value in RGB model. Does A makes the difference here. Since my next frame is like a stencil which set the pixels only to what is changed. At the moment the A value is 0.

Comment: When setting pixel, I am not setting the a value in the a,r,g,b color model. Does setting a to 0 that is not transparent will make the difference?

Comment: I checked the number of frames and ImageHeight * Image width. It seems to be fine.

Comment: Based on the code you've provided, there is nothing wrong with fbdev. Your code overwriting image each frame - i suppose it's wrong. Also worth noting - usually alpha=0 means absolute transparency; it's alpha=255 which is opaque.

Comment: I have attached the Windows Version too, this works fine. I am confused, why it fails in linux.

Comment: @SHREYASJOSHI: How often per frame is `SetPixel()` called? How often is `SETBACKGROUND()` calles?

Comment: For the first frame, it called 135386 times.For the next frame, it is called 3153. This makes sense as the second frame will put pixel only for the changed one's not the entire one.

Comment: It doesn't call the SETBACKGROUND() as expected.

Comment: I am pressing one thing that the same code works on WIndows but not in Linux. The only thing changed here is the RGB calculation and the Display control. In linux, it is Framebuffer and windows it is Hwnd.

Comment: Use a GIF animation that doesn't change the first pixel in the second frame (i.e. first frame sets it and it doesn't change afterwards). What do you get when you print the RGB values of that pixel on each frame? Print the values in `fbp` and `local_display_mem`, please.

Comment: Superbly great! You hit the nail, it is the value that created the problem. The '\0' is not equal to 255 in linux. In windows, however '\0' is 255. I don't why? but that was the issue.

Comment: Which `'\0'` are you referring to?